# New Java Technology JAXX

Tags: java, new-operator

Can any one give me detailed information about Java's new technology that is JAXX.

Really I have searched all over the web but not getting exact details that could help me to 
write program in Java JAXX ,Compilation  & run the same.
It is a new technology ahead of Swing.

Thanks.

Comment: this reference is from 2006, http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/03/30/introducing-jaxx.html I wouldn't say it's new... nor well accepted.

Comment: yes i have gone through java.net link but there is no detailed information nor getting any code or how to create project using it.I have downloaded jaxx-runtime.jar

Comment: @ harry ok I got your point.I will work on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Ethan Nicholas' work on Jaxx is not a dead project.

Read here for good introduction: today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/03/30/introducing-jaxx.html

JavaCSS is found in the JAXX project. JAXX is a xml format style implementation of the swing gui interface. You write an xml document, and a css style document, and are able to bind the inputs and outputs of the GUI to your java implementation engine. The css style document allows for rapid sophisticated gui development. Using the jaxx jar engine, the xml code is converted into java code that runs as rapidly as if deployed in a .java class file.

The project has been continued by a French group of programmers and is now to be found here:

http://www.nuiton.org/projects/jaxx/files

The latest release is JAXX 2.4.2. The latest update was May or June 2011. Whilst in French, the documentation is still comprehensible in English. Just translate.

The original ethan nicholas files of jaxx were last updated on 17-07-2009

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jaxx/

Please note: www.jaxxframework.org/wiki/Main_Page is a dead link, the site is discontinued. instead a mirror has been made and can be found at: buix.labs.libre-entreprise.org/original-jaxx/www.jaxxframework.org/wiki/Main_Page.html

This documentation is essential to understand the meaning and purpose of jaxx and its use.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this link??

http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/03/30/introducing-jaxx.html

The resource is pretty good and has a few links at the end for further reading.

Without more detail of your issues, its all I can offer.

Note: I would suggest however that this project doesnt look very active.

Comment: yes i have gone through java.net link but there is no detailed information nor getting any code or how to create project using it.I have downloaded jaxx-runtime.jar..I have also wrote a program but it asks for JNLP so stuck up at that point.

Comment: JNLP is for launching your app from a browser...it shouldnt be required. we need more detail of your issue.

Comment: <Application title='Hello'>
  <VBox horizontalAlignment='center'   margin='6, 6, 6, 6'>

    <JLabel text='Hello, World!'  foreground='red'  font-size='24'/>
    <JButton text='Close'   onActionPerformed='dispose()'/>

  </VBox>
</Application> I have written this code and Hello.jaxx is created but getting this exception after executing it.MissingFieldException[ The following required field is missing from the launch file: <jnlp>]
 at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat.parse(Unknown Source)